# cannot import moveit_commander

Tags: ros, python, moveit, ros-kinetic, moveit-commander

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04 and when i try to import moveit_commander it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from planning_scene_interface import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/planning_scene_interface.py", line 48, in <module>
    import pyassimp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyassimp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyassimp/core.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import structs
ImportError: cannot import name structs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256124/cannot-import-moveit_commander/) by [M_Allam](https://answers.ros.org/users/28027/m_allam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known issue, see [ros-planning/moveit#86](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/86).

[ros-planning/moveit#450](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/450) should presumably fix this, but I'm not sure whether that has been released yet. If not, building the `moveit_commander` package from source (in your Catkin workspace) works (note that you probably only need that particular package in your workspace).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-04**:
Yes, the fix is not yet released. I opened [a release request](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/457).

**Comment by [AndyChou007](https://answers.ros.org/users/34792/andychou007/) on 2018-04-27**:
Has this bug been fixed? I still cannot import moveit_commander on Ubuntu 16.04 and pyassimp 3.2
I have seen ros-planning/moveit#450 #86, yet I didn't find some useful solution.
could you give me a detailed advice on handling with terminal?
PS: I have built the moveit_commander package from source.